# variadic templates and initializer lists type narrowing differences

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, initializer-list

So this does not make any sense.

With this class:

```
template< typename T, int nDimensions = 2 >
class Vec {
private:
std::array< T, nDimensions > elements_;

public:
typedef T ValueType;

Vec() : elements_() {}

template <typename... U>
Vec(U... ts) : elements_{ ts... } {}

Vec(const std::initializer_list<T>& values){
    std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), elements_.begin());
}

template <typename T2, int nDimension2>
Vec(Vec<T2, nDimension2> const& copy){
    for (int i = 0; i < nDimensions; i++){
        this->elements_[i] = (T)static_cast<T2>(copy[i]);
    }
}
};
```

Why is it perfectly fine to do:

```
Vec<int,2> twoi = { 1, 2.1 }; //An int and a double
```

But not:

```
Vec<int,2> twoi2(1,2.1); //conversion from 'double' to 'int' requires a narrowing conversion
```

That just does not seem intuitive. For the Initializer list it just preforms the conversion, while on the other hand when the template is expanded, it should just hand over the double which gets converted to a int.

This is what the function should be expanded out too if I'm correct:

```
std::array< int, 2> elements_ = { 1.2,1};
```

Which compiles just fine.

Is there a way to modify this constructor to ignore the conversions?

Visual Studios 2015 Update 3 build:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MathTests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>d:\projects\stevenstuff\mathtests\source.cpp(12): warning C4838: conversion from 'double' to 'int' requires a narrowing conversion
1>d:\projects\stevenstuff\mathtests\source.cpp(12): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>d:\projects\stevenstuff\util\vec\include\vec.h(19): error C2397: conversion from 'const double' to 'int' requires a narrowing conversion
1>  d:\projects\stevenstuff\mathtests\source.cpp(10): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'Vec<int,2>::Vec<double,int>(const double &,const int &)' being compiled
```

Comment:  I'm getting a narrowing error for both on gcc.

Comment: I'm gettig a narrowing error for `= { 1, 2.1 }` and a narrowing _warning_ for `(1,2.1)` with gcc8.1. Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1eaf476d542383b9

Comment: Yea, @TrebuchetMS I been googling, and it seems that this behavior changes wildly between versions aswell. FYI: I'm compiling with visual studios.

Comment: What version of MSVS are you using?  It's C++11 support wasn't considered complete until 2015 update 3. MSVS 2017 fails to compile both as expected.

Comment: @NathanOliver updated

Comment: I don't get the Q now.  You show that you are getting an error but you say you aren't.  Also not that as far as the standard cares a warning and an error are the same thing.

Comment: @NathanOliver The question is, why does it work one way, but not the other even when there both damn near the same thing. And how can I improve the constructor to not cause errors/warning

Comment: Well, technically it doesn't work one way and not the other.  You re getting a warning and if you turn on warnings as errors it will stop compiling.  As far as not causing warnings or error, what do you want to have happen in a case where you use an initializer list of different types?

Comment: @NathanOliver If I provide Vec<int,3> temp(3.5,1,0.1f); or Vec<int,3> temp2 ={3.5,1,0.1f}; I'm expecting each of these arguments to be casted to an int. Resulting in: {3,1,0} in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, eventually.

Simple answer is, theres is a conversion that needs to happen. Some compilers are fine with it and just cast directly, some don't and complain that its impossible. Way around it is to slip a sneaky cast into the the constructor.

```
template <typename... U>
    Vec(const U&... ts) 
        : elements_{(T)(ts)... } {
    }
```

Then everything gets expanded as: elements_((T)ts[1]... ext.